# How to increase the size of driver partition in VM?

Tags: partitioning, virtual-machine, gparted

In my VM, there are three partitions as shown in this figure:
[Partition layout in Ggarted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjWaj.jpg)

But the ROOT partition /dev/vda1 is only 888.65MB now, I want to expand its size. The root partition is the first partition, then how can I expand it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would probably be easier to clone the `/` partition to a new virtual disk.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the 888.65M represents the free space of the / root partion and not the total size.

You could add another partition to your vm and then expand the / partion using the recently added free space. In your actual configuration you can extend it since you have no free space

Comment: But the problem is if I add more free space, i could only extend /dev/vda3, since /dev/vda1 is blocked by swap and vda3. I could not exend it directly.